# I want to display key/value pairs as columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am having a terrible time trying to display some key/value pairs in Excel as columns a specific way.
*Note: I have found a way to accomplish this in Python so this question is mostly for the sake of curiosity*

I have a small data set consisting of key/value pairs:

| Person | Item |
| --- | --- |
| Steve | Apple |
| Steve | Orange |
| Bob | Potato |
| Bob | Grape |
| Bob | Cherry |
| Bob | Orange |
| Bob | Watermelon |
| Max | Cherry |
| Max | Apple |
| Max | Potato |
| Max | Orange |

My goal is to simplify the data and show it with the "persons" (keys) as labels, and remove duplicates:

| Person | Steve | Bob | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| - | Apple | Potato | Cherry |
| - | Orange | Grape | Apple |
| - | - | Cherry | Potato |
| - | - | Orange | Orange |
| - | - | Watermelon | - |

So far, the closest I've gotten is to make everything a pivot table, and set both fields as Rows, with the first one being "Person".
https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3nC4.png

This sorts the items under the correct person, and I would "just" need to split those in seperate columns. This seems really simple, yet I cannot figure out how. I am fairly certain this can easily be accomplished with VBA but I wanted to find a way using Excel's default tools.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: AFAIK, Excel's pivot table does really allow to pivot with some kind of mathematical aggregation. So you need to use either Power Query (which can Pivot without aggregation), VBA or formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1** Please copy the Person column to other cells, and use **Remove Duplicates** (Data tab > Data tools group) to get uniqure person names.

**Step 2** Please copy the person names, go to Home tab > Clipboard group > expand Paste option > **Transpose(T)**. Then you would get the person names as titles.

**Step 3** Enter the formula `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$12,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$12=G$2,ROW($1:$12),4^8),ROW(A1))),"")` to get the iterms for each person. Please note, as this formula is an array formula, you need to press Ctrl + Alt + Enter after you enter it into Formula Bar to add curly braces of the array.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's a good option, would still like to know if there's a way using pivot tables though...